# Why is there no link to timeline of the post?

Tags: support, status-completed, timeline

I can see the timeline of a question:

```
{site}/posts/{post_id}/timeline
```

But there is no link to it. Maybe I can't just find it or it is located in the place hard to see. But if there is really no link to the timeline, then why? I found timeline pretty interesting. (see, for example, the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/timeline) of [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array))

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post

Comment: Because that feature is somewhat unmaintained and not useful for the general public.

Comment: They already built a new one for moderators (which is heaps and bounds better), so that thing is not at all maintained. As in, if they accidentally broke it at some point, they'd probably just remove the page... They refer to that specific timeline as a "failed project."

Comment: @Payeli Well that one is built into the admin panel, so he'd have to get access to that first. ;P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am happy to report that there is now a link to the timeline available for all users. More details [are available here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/51).

Comment: Got it. It shocked and confused me because I remember never seeing this before, so I even doubt if my memory is reliable...

Comment: Looks like 6-8 weeks now means 6-8 years

Comment: Glad to accept it after 6 years 

Answer (score 15):

[Because it is experimental.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post/180594#180594)

> Realistically, this particular view is only occasionally useful, and even less often used.
>
> I use [a script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) to add a link to the timeline to every post. And I *still* almost never click it. The link does occasionally break page layouts though.
>
> ...
>
> Sometimes, experiments produce nothing of lasting value but the knowledge gained from watching them. And that's ok.

We used what we learned there to make a much better timeline view for moderators, who actually do have a fairly regular need to integrate *tons and tons of obscure* information about a given post. The old one remains for those who want it, but we've no plans to enhance it further.