# Why wasn't this duplicate question closed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I've voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839145/ensure-padding-around-markers-on-google-maps-for-web) as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339365/google-maps-api-3-fitbounds-padding-ensure-markers-are-not-obscured-by-overlai), which although newer, has better answers. As far as I've seen, [the question with better answers should be favored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers/252017#252017), even if it's newer than its duplicate. However, neither question was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Looks like the flag simply aged away.  Many *many* more questions get flagged for closure than can actually get closed by the people handling them, so most flags just end up aging away.  Newer questions are prioritized, so when you flag a 5 year old question there's a 99.9% chance that nothing will happen as a result of the flag.  The best fix for closing old duplicates is to get a gold tag badge.

Comment: Maybe we need a merge option very soon.

Comment: @ManojKumar We've had a merge option for years.  It's *harder* to get a merge than to close questions as duplicates.  (I also don't see a need for these questions to be merged.)

Answer (score 1):

From the question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6839145/timeline), you can see that the question has been in the Close Vote review queue but no reviews have been made. After 4 days your close vote [ages away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system). But, thanks to the meta effect, the question is now <s>on 4 close votes again and I expect it will be closed soon</s> closed.

Comment: Didn't know about the timeline, is there a UI for this from the question page?

Comment: @DanDascalescu [no](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262678/why-is-there-no-link-to-timeline-of-the-post) (unless you use a user script).

Comment: "If the newest vote (of the same type) on the post is older than **14** days" it says in your ages away link, unless the question has 100+ views *and* it was kicked out of the review queue (in which case it is 4 days).