# Guidance on flagging an off-topic question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-flags

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621920/what-are-some-of-the-pros-and-cons-for-using-sam-vs-serverless-framework) but my flag was disputed.

I cannot remember which flag I used, but I would like to know if this is just a fine question or off-topic and a clear case for closing to get better at flagging.

Does this look like:

- a "recommendation" question,
- an opinion-based question,
- a general computing hardware and software question,
- or - my guess - a "professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault" question?

Comment: FYI: You flagged it as primarily opinion based and it got disputed in review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18140727

Comment: @JonClements Is there a way for flaggers to see those review links? I'm a bit confused because as somebody with 193 rep I can always see the results of a view with a link, but I don't seem to see the resulting reviews from flags.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, I was struggling which flag to pick.

Comment: @jrh if you look at a post's timeline you can see completed reviews listed there.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, but I'm still not quite sure what you're referring to, if I click on the "10 months ago" part of "Active: 10 months ago" it just brings me back to the same page, is there a different way to access the timeline? E.g., I flagged [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706542/a-bar-to-indicator-the-percentage-but-not-a-progress-bar/11741035#11741035) as a duplicate but the edit history is still blank and the "last active" thing just takes me to the newest answer.

Comment: @jrh have a read through: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340703/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post

Comment: @JonClements, gosh.. I learned today how to see timelines: take [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621920/what-ablablabla`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621920) and make it manually [`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47621920/timeline`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47621920/timeline). Why there is no a link to timeline somewhere?

Comment: @Sinatr the latest I'm aware of is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262678/why-is-there-no-link-to-timeline-of-the-post

Comment: @JonClements, haha... still experimental. I see.

Comment: Well - I believe it's now complete and not experimental - just the people that use it tend to have userscripts that do it and no one's brought it up recently (as far as I'm aware...)

Comment: IIRC it is a very uncommon path, and including it in the post menu would apparently break the UI in certain situations, so they won't be adding a link. Just change the URL for those rare occurrences where you would need it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question

> In general, what would be pros and cons of choosing SAM over serverless or vice-versa?

Is *possibly* opinion-based, I can't tell. One would need domain knowledge to tell. It might be that there's an industry de facto standard, where one way is always better.

However, a question asking for "general pros and cons" is too broad for SO. This question should be closed for that reason.

> Can you write SAM in serverless.yaml? Like SAM has some useful features and if we could utilize them in serverless that would be great

This is specific, but also a yes/no question. It seem like either the answer would be something easily found in documentation, or this is an invitation to a discussion.

Overall, the question opens up for discussion. It would not be wrong to flag it as neither "primarily opinion-based" or "too broad". According to a diamond mod you flagged it as primarily-opinion based, so you did the right thing.

---

The 4 people who did the triage review caused by the flag, appears to be - at a glance:

- One paying attention
- One not paying attention
- One rookie reviewer, who might have yet to learn
- One "robo-reviewer"

The latter 3 let the question through.

Comment: so, we should flag the robo-reviewer, right?

Comment: @Cœur SO insists on having review audits that should catch and automatically punish robo-reviewers. But of course the audits don't do that very often; they mostly just punish volunteers doing work for free, who have done nothing wrong... I'd let SO employees handle robo-reviewes themselves, manually, until the audits are fixed.